# Word for "Approve or Deny"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrases

I am looking for a word to describe someone who approves or denies something. However, the word must start with a "C". Here is how it is so far:

```
# CueCreator   <-- The person who creates the Cue
# CueCompleter <-- The person who completes the Cue
# Cue?         <-- The person who determines whether the Completed Cue is valid or invalid
```

"CueDECIDER" might be OK in meaning, but the word needs to start with a C. Any ideas?

Comment: How about CueRater (joke :-D)

Comment: CueCloser? Closer ; Someone that closes a deal/shop/negoziation etc. –

Comment: *CueChooser, CueConcluder, CueCincher, CueClincher*, etc etc etv

Comment: CueCumber. [Because of course it is](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+cumber).

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas immediately spring to mind;

**CueController**

I think this fits in well with your existing roles.

from [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/controller?show=0&t=1415384085)

> a person who directs the action of something

and

**CueCommissioner**

This sounds like a more important role than CueController.

from [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commissioner)

> one of a group of people who have been given the official job of finding information about something or controlling something

At a push, **CueCurator** might work.It sounds too much like CueCreator though and would no doubt lead to much confusion.

from [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/curator)

> one who has the care and superintendence of something

Answer (score 1):

How about CueConfirmer or CueCertifier?

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider Cue Concluder?

Comment: Hmm, that seems like a little bit of a stretch. Perhaps semantically it's ok, but I have never heard that word used in all my life in spoken English.